# Serial.serialutil.serialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port

I am using Python code to control my mini GRBL CNC machine that connected to Laptop with windows operating system over MQTT Protocol,

Here is the code.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import serial

# Open grbl serial port
s = serial.Serial('COM5',115200)

# Wake up grbl
s.write("\r\n\r\n")
time.sleep(2)   # Wait for grbl to initialize 
s.flushInput()  # Flush startup text in serial input

f = """
O1000
T1 M6
(Linear / Feed - Absolute)
G0 G90 G40 G21 G17 G94 G80
G54 X-75 Y-75 S500 M3  (Position 6)
G43 Z100 H1
Z5
G1 Z-20 F100
X-40                   (Position 1)
Y40 M8                 (Position 2)
X40                    (Position 3)
Y-40                   (Position 4)
X-75                   (Position 5)
Y-75                   (Position 6)
G0 Z100
M30
"""

# Runs when the client receives a CONNACK connection acknowledgement.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, result_code):
    print "Successful connection."
    # Subscribe to your topics here.
    client.subscribe("hi")

# Runs when a message is PUBLISHed from the broker. Any messages you receive
# will run this callback.
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    if message.topic == "hi":
        if message.payload == "run":

            # Stream g-code to grbl
            for line in f:
                l = line.strip() # Strip all EOL characters for consistency
                print 'Sending: ' + l,
                s.write(l + '\n') # Send g-code block to grbl
                grbl_out = s.readline() # Wait for grbl response with carriage return
                print ' : ' + grbl_out.strip()

                # Close file and serial 
                s.close()
                # You could do something here if you wanted to.
        elif message.payload == "STOP":
            # Received "STOP". Do the corresponding thing here.
            # Close file and serial 
                s.close()
                print "CNC is stopped."

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("iot.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

But when i run it i got

```
successful connection
```

and then,

`serial.serialutil.serialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open` ,Although the CNC works fine from GUI.At first i thought that the opening GUI caused this error, but even when i closed it i am still having the same issue.So, maybe i am facing this problem because of MQTT, maybe it's a security issue because when i run that python code but without using PAHO MQTT protocol every things works fine, the same port opens and CNC works.

Isn't it supposed to work until i send "`run`" because the serial opening order comes after receiving the message?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MQTT, it's all about access to the serial port. Most likely some other application is locking the port

Comment: Ok, how i should know

Comment: Also, it opens from GUI

Comment: No idea, I have no way of knowing what software is running on your system

Comment: please read my question again @hardillb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the serial port when ever you get a message delivered. That means you can only ever process one message.

Comment: Why, is that normal ,how i can reopen the port @hardilb

Comment: I have no idea why YOU are closing the serial port on each message, I didn't write the code.

Comment: I got it, thank u so much for your help, i think i will keep asking these stupid questions until i learn